# Low-level communication on Android/other mobile platforms

Tags: android, mobile, communication, gsm, low-level

Android has it's NDK to handle native code. I was just wondering how deep you can go with low level programming on this platform - whether you can for example control what the phone transmits through the GSM/UMTS network or see the raw data that are received.

*Is working with the embedded phone modem generally possible on this/other platforms within the scope of their APIs?*

I presume that interfering with the lower communication layers (like adding compression to the voice data, change of encoding and so on) means playing with the firmware of the communication modules and is generally something that the phone manufacturers don't support officially.

*Anyway is there something about this topics you can recommend to read or search for?*

Comment: Normally, I think you won't be able to reach low-level APIs. Android is open-source, you can check how it works on low-level, but your application will not be able to reach the modem in a low-level way, because the APIs are not public. Moreover, the NDK maintains a list of stable APIs. Using anything else will mean that your app might not work on a future device (as the API might have changed in the meantime).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please be more specific about the other low-level APIs? Im targeting a specific device, so future portability is not a problem right now. Should I look for some device specific API then?

Comment: Checking for device-specific APIs is a good idea (the manufacturer might have such), but I'm afraid they won't have any public APIs (as they don't expose such critical functionality usually), so you will need to explore everything via NDK and low-level research. Unfortunately, I don't know this field, so I can't really help more. I'll post some links in an answer (hopefully you will get a much better and useful answer too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A public API package (it's not really rich in terms of your requirements):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html

About the low-level APIs (the Radio Interface Layer of Android), you can read here:
[http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/telephony.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430043507/http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/telephony.html)

About implementing (modifying) the RIL:
[http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/telephony.html#androidTelephonyRILImplementing](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430043507/http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/telephony.html#androidTelephonyRILImplementing)

In this case, however, you need to touch the Android source code, so for application development, it is not an option.

Comment: Under the RIL, there's the baseband firmware that interprets, process and generates the packets which are transmitted to the network provider. The baseband firmware is device-specific, closed-source and proprietary. So you are limited to the RIL level, that implements [AT commands](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AT_Commands) to talk to the baseband modem. That's how far you can go with root privileges. See [this topic on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49348821) for more info.